# External DV camera not found with flash for ustream or justin.tv on OS X in Chrome, Safari and firefox

Tags: google-chrome, osx-lion, flash, camera, dv

I have Canon DV camera (MV850i), Macbook pro (early 2008), OS X Lion.

MY DV camera works fine with in OS X and iMovie and I can image capture using a firewire cable.

What I am trying to do is capture live video and broadcast it through an online service.  I have tried both ustream and justintv.  I have tried using Safari, Chrome and firefox (latest versions and latest flash updates performed).

The issue I have is the flash does not recognise the external DV camera.  It only shows my iSight camera.

So how can I broadcast live video?

Comment: is the correct forum for this type of question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Use firefox and downgrade flash from 11.x to 10.3.  This enabled the flash to find the DV camera and stream with no issues.

You can find instructions for uninstalling current Adobe Flash Player on OS X here:
http://www.blogsdna.com/4329/how-to-uninstall-adobe-flash-player-on-windows-mac.htm

Download link for Flash Player 10.3:
http://mac.oldapps.com/flash_player.php?old_flash_player=11?download